# RichTextBox not showing formfeed character

Tags: c#, richtextbox, linefeed

I have a text file that, when I open it in Notepad, shows the form feed character (byte 12). I want to show this character in my richtextbox but no matter which encoding I use when I read the text file it won't show. When I enter the character myself it shows. When I do `myRTB.Text = "♀"` it shows, but when I do

```
myRTB.Text = File.ReadAllText(myFileName.txt);
```

it doesn't show. I've also tried using the readers in the Encoding class to no avail.

How can I show the form feed character in my rtb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help @jmcilhinney and @Damith. I ended up cheating the system by doing a dirty. I saw that myRTB was replacing the form feed char with `\page` in the RTF, but when I typed the form feed char myself it put `\u9792`. Therefore I went with the hack:

```
myRTB.Rtf = myRTB.Rtf.Replace("\\page", "\\u9792");
```

If you have something less hackish that I can get working please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

try with `ReadAllText`

```
myRTB.Text = File.ReadAllText(myFileName.txt, Encoding.Unicode);
```

Comment: Dang, it doesn't like `Encoding.Unicode` or any other Encoding type. It says Invalid File Format

Comment: have you try with `myRTB.LoadFile("myFileName.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);`

Comment: Yeah, it didn't like how the file was formatted or it didn't include the form feed character, or it gave me Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a line feed has a value of 13.  If you have characters with the value 12 in there then they are not line feeds.

As for your issue, `ReadAllLines` reads the lines of a file into a `String` array, thus stripping out all the line breaks.  You might do as Damith suggests and call `ReadAllText`, which reads the file contents as a single `String`, and assign the result to the `Text` property or else call `ReadAllLines` and assign the result to the `Lines` property.  Better to call `LoadFile` on the `RichTextBox` itself though.

Comment: Sorry, I got line feed and form feed confused. Actually line feed is 10, and form feed is 12. (Asciitable.com) I'll edit my post. I tried LoadFile but it doesn't like my file format.

Comment: B*gger!  I always get carriage return and line feed mixed up.  What a couple of silly billies we are. ;-)  With regards to your file format, I take it that it's not RTF.  In that case you must use the overload that lets you specify a `RichTextBoxStreamType`.  Make sure to use an appropriate value based on your encoding.